# Set priority for bluetooth interface

Tags: usb, bluetooth, 22.04

I just migrated from Windows to Ubuntu as my main OS. I own a bluetooth dongle which I use for connecting my wireless headphones to my computer. The thing is, my PC does NOT have integrated bluetooth, which is no problem since I use the dongle, on Windows I just had to plug it in and pair whatever device I wanted; when using Ubuntu for any reason it shows `hci1` and is scanning for nearby devices as if my PC had bluetooth. The dongle shows as `hci0` but I can't get to use it as the main interface.

I tried `sudo hciconfig hci1 down` to see if Ubuntu would use the remaining interface (USB dongle) but no luck so far, as it disables bluetooth.

I just need to set interfaces so `hci0` (dongle) is used as main. Maybe editing any interfaces config file?

```
 > hci0:    Type: Primary  Bus: USB     BD Address: removed for privacy  ACL MTU:
      1021:6  SCO MTU: 255:12   UP RUNNING PSCAN    RX bytes:5761 acl:0 sco:0
      events:352 errors:0   TX bytes:35512 acl:0 sco:0 commands:352 errors:0
        Features: 0xff 0xff 0xff 0xfe 0xdb 0xfd 0x7b 0x87   Packet type: DM1
      DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3   Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF PARK
        Link mode: PERIPHERAL ACCEPT    Name: 'Ubuntu-tosh #1'  Class:
      0x7c0104  Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Object Transfer,
      Audio, Telephony  Device Class: Computer, Desktop workstation     HCI
      Version: 5.1 (0xa)  Revision: 0x9a9   LMP Version: 5.1 (0xa) 
      Subversion: 0x8a6b    Manufacturer: Realtek Semiconductor Corporation
      (93)
    
 > hci1:    Type: Primary  Bus: USB     BD Address: removed for privacy  ACL MTU:
      339:8  SCO MTU: 128:2     UP RUNNING      RX bytes:6683 acl:0 sco:0
      events:303 errors:0   TX bytes:3755 acl:0 sco:0 commands:282 errors:0
        Features: 0xff 0x3e 0x85 0x30 0x18 0x18 0x00 0x00   Packet type: DM1
      DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3   Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF 
        Link mode: PERIPHERAL ACCEPT    Name: 'Ubuntu-tosh'     Class: 0x000104
        Service Classes: Unspecified    Device Class: Computer, Desktop
      workstation   HCI Version: 2.0 (0x3)  Revision: 0xc5c     LMP Version: 2.0
      (0x3)  Subversion: 0xc5c  Manufacturer: Cambridge Silicon Radio (10)
```

EDIT:

I got a way to make it work, while having the dongle plugged in just restart bluetooth service using CLI, but this is not a reliable solution as I would have to do it everytime I turn on the computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a udev rule to remove the other device

```
sudo touch /etc/udev/rules.d/81-bluetooth-hci.rules
```

Put this into that file after `sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/81-bluetooth-hci.rules`

```
 SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0a12", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0001", ATTR{authorized}="0"
```

Reboot and `hciconfig` should only show one device